# Enum property name is not following the convention in bad request response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

An `API` endpoint has following signature

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromBody] SingInRequest request)
    {
            //
            return Ok();
    }
```

The request has following format:

```
public class SingInRequest
{
    [Required]
    public SignInTypeEnum SingInType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public enum SignInTypeEnum
{
    Password,
    Facebook,
}
```

Now, if I make an `API` call with body of contents:

```
{
    "singInType": "Google",
    "code": null
}
```

Error looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-437d79899771614482f4016f6e1e1aba-a7059b70a5027d41-00",
    "errors": {
        "Code": [
            "The Code field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

On the other hand, when `enum` is missing:

```
{
    "singInType": null,
    "code": "abc"
}
```

The error is:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-17df65fe9542e44fb882f06ee6b71f18-0e02e133ef4b9b4d-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.singInType": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to SharedLib.Requests.Auth.SignInTypeEnum. Path: $.singInType | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 22."
        ]
    }
}
```

So

- for non-enum properties in bad request the names look like this: `Code`.
- for enum the name is: `$.singInType`.

I would like all fields/properties to follow the same PascalCase convention i.e. I expect enum field to be named `SignInType`, not `$.singInType`

Is it possible to get rid of this leading `$.` string for enum errors? Or in other words make all fields behave in the same way?

p.s. I use `System.Text.Json` and .net 5

Comment: Make property nullable?

Comment: Nope, same problem when you post random value

Comment: Have you tried not having them spelled different? Your JSON has "sing" instead of "sign". My guess is you're getting different behavior between it and "Code" because it can't even map "singInType" to the property of "SignInType" just based on spelling.

Comment: Enum could be named anything, even `AbracadabraEnum` as an example :) The JSON body is mapped to the fields, not to the types names. But you made a valid point on spelling mistake. I will correct it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I found on the topic

https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/enum-as-required-field-in-asp-net-core-webapi

> The Problem When creating a model for a WebApi project you sometimes
> have a need/want to use ENUMs as properties. Sometimes they can be
> nullable which is straight forward, but sometimes you want to ensure a
> value is passed in from the user. That’s what I’ll be discussing here.
>
> What is Going On??? One day I created a simple model with an ENUM
> property that I expected to be required so I did what I usually did
> and added a `[Required]` attribute and kept moving thinking that would
> make sure if the client forgot to pass me a value they would get an
> error.
>
> However, when they sent me a request with an empty value for the ENUM
> their query still succeeded. Then I started scratching my head… “Why
> was my required attribute not working???”, I asked myself and my team.
>
> Turns out… The problem faced here is nested in the order of operations
> of converting the body to JSON and validating the model validations.
>
> First, .NET de-serializes the body into JSON with default values. This
> means if you pass in a null value for a non-nullable ENUM the default
> value will be set for it (the first item in the ENUM usually). Same
> thing happens for privatives.
>
> Second, the ModelState gets validated, however, since the JSON parser
> already added a default value for the ENUM (or primitives) there is
> technically no error.
> The Fix To remedy this if I want an ENUM or PRIMATIVE to be “required”
> I do not use `[Required]`… I use `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` which makes the property always required in the
> JSON body. So now when the body is de-serialized an error will be
> raised instead of using the default value for the ENUM or PRIMATIVE.

**Source: Medium- Michael Tarleton**

Ok, so technically it's another problem, but realistically my code is also affected by it. When I provide no value for `enum` - request goes through with default value.. The solution to the problem provided in post above is for the problem described in the post. I have no idea if it fixes my problem as well. Since I am not using the  **Newtownsoft Json** package I cannot apply the suggested fix for my solution.

In a meanwhile, the solution that I have came up with (while there are no other answers) - is simply using a **string** in request and handling validation in controller afterwards:

```
public class SingInRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string SingInType { get; set; } // validated in controller

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then,

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SingInResponse), 200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(
        [FromBody] SingInRequest request)
    {
        var parseResult = Enum.TryParse<SignInTypeEnum>(request.SingInType, true, out SignInTypeEnum singInType);
        if (!parseResult)
        {
            var response = new ValidationFailureResponse();
            response.AddError("SingInType", "Invalid sign-in type");

            return BadRequest(response);
        }
    }
```

Class `ValidationFailureResponse` mimics the bad request response.

```
public class ValidationFailureResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public void AddError(string fieldName, string errorMessage)
    {
        if (Errors.ContainsKey(fieldName))
        {
            Errors[fieldName].Add(errorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Errors.Add(fieldName, new List<string>() { errorMessage });
        }
    }
}
```

Example Request/Response

```
{
    "singInType": "aa",
    "code": "abc"
}

{
    "errors": {
        "SingInType": [
            "Invalid sign-in type"
        ]
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "code": "abc"
}

{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-3c4821800f74f048a2d3b2c8a4cba9da-6826e2c0c3cd514b-00",
    "errors": {
        "SingInType": [
            "The SingInType field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I will be glad to see better solutions to the problem than this :)

Comment: In this solution you have possibly accidentally fixed your spelling issues. It's still spelled wrong, but at least it's spelled the same way everywhere. You should see what happens if you correct that in your original code.

Comment: Hey thank you for noticing the spelling mistake. Although it's not related to the problem, I still need to correct the spelling :) As I meantioned in another comment under the question - the `Enum` itself could be named anything.